# List full lines not matching keywords from second file

Tags: text-processing

I have a simple text file containing a list of HTML links in this format:

```
<a href="https://xxxxxxxx" target="_blank" rel="">This_is_a_test001</a><br />
```

and a second text file containing a list of keywords. I'd like to extract the FULL lines from the first file that don't match any of the keywords in the second file. I'm happy to use any tool or scripting language there is.

Comment: Hint: the tool is `grep`, see `man grep`.

Comment: The tool might also be `awk` depending on how the keywords are to be matched on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -vFf keywords.txt file.txt
```

Would list the lines of `file.txt` that don't contain any of lines of `keywords.txt`.

```
awk -F '[<>]' '!x{k[$0]; next}; ! ($3 in k)' keywords.txt x=1 file.txt
```

Would list the lines of `file.txt` where the portion in between the second and third occurrence of a `<` or `>` is not found in `keywords.txt`.

Comment: I assumed grep wasn't what I needed as I had spurious characters in my keywords file, so filtering didn't work. Your grep solution works, but for some reason the awk one returns no results. Anyway solved, thanks!

Comment: @MarkRoi, sorry I overlooked that `! $3 in k` would be interpreted as `(! $3) in k`, so we need `! ($3 in k)`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command to get the result as per requirement

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $0}' Keyword_file first_file


Keyword_file===> Consists of keyword in first column
```

Above command removes the lines from first_file when it matches any of keyword present in keyword_file and display the remaining line

Below is the example for the same

Let me know for any confusion

```
Example

keyword_file
praveen
ajay
san


first_file

praveen is good
san is bad
abhi is great
kiran is awesome

command: awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $0}' Keyword_file first_file

output

abhi is great
kiran is awesome
```